# How can I use a range for to traverse an array backwards in C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

This is how I traverse an array from first to last element:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[4]={0,1,2,3}, i=0;
    for (auto i : a)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is is possible to traverse it backwards using the same loop? If so, how?

Comment: No, the range-for only iterates forward. If you can modify the container you could reverse it first?

Comment: Also note that you have two *different* variables named `i` in your program.